# How to get the device to remember an int or string

Tags: android, save, int

I am creating a quiz app and when one quiz is completed I set an int called iftesttaken to be 1 so the quiz can no longer be taken. This works well until the app is closed and then quiz can be re taken which isn't what I want. Is there are anyway that iftesttaken can be saved or remembered so that the quiz can never be taken again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences. For example to save some string:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putString("StringtoSave", myString).commit();
```

Then, when you start your app, you read the string

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
myString = prefs.getString("StringtoSave", "");
```